# Read number of characters in a column of a GuiTableControl object

Tags: vba, scripting, sap-gui

I'm trying to read the number of characters in column "**MRP element data**" in tcode `MD04`.

Below code is giving me 1 but I want it to give 16 or it should give 16 provided that my code is right...If there is one more row with one more Purchase Order it should give 32 etc.

[image]

```
j = 0

Do

  session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subINCLUDE1XX:SAPMM61R:0750/tblSAPMM61RTC_EZ/txtMDEZ-EXTRA[5," & CStr(j) & "]").caretPosition = 0

  objSheet.Cells(i, 2) = Len(Cstr(j))

  Exit Do

  j =j + 1

Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You currently calculate the length of the integer variable `j` which contains the value `0`, it's why you get `1`.

The table element you show is a [`GuiTableControl`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/latest/en-US?q=GuiTableControl) object. You will find the method `GetCell` to read the content of a cell, and after that you can calculate the length of its value.

```
Set tableControl = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subINCLUDE1XX:SAPMM61R:0750/tblSAPMM61RTC_EZ")

MsgBox Len(tableControl.GetCell(1,5).Text)
```

(row 1 = second row; column 5 = sixth column)

Comment: Thank you Sandra! May I ask how did you see that it's `GuiTableControl` ?

Comment: I'm trying to do a script for goods receipt. First step is to take a product number from Excel input file and access MD04. If there are 2 open PO's the GR should be handled manually but if it's only one PO it should copy it and go to MIGO to perform GR. So I tried `If Len(tableControl.GetCell(2,5).Text) > 1 then objSheet.Cells(i, 2) = "To be handled manually"` Else copy from Row 1 = second row. But the script stops when there is only Row 1 (one PO). Is it possible to use string like this `If Len(tableControl.GetCell(Cstr(j),5).Text) > 16 then` to read amount of characters in entire

Comment: Basically when Row 2 = third row is available it should move on to next product number. Only when Row 1 is existent (no Row 2 available) it should copy PO number from Row 1 and move on to MIGO perform GR.

Comment: I assume it's perhaps better do do some kind of row count. `objSheet.Cells(i, 2) = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subINCLUDE1XX:SAPMM61R:0750/tblSAPMM61RTC_EZ").rowcount` gives me 47 if there is only one PO (Row 1 = second row) and 48 when there are two PO's (also on Row 2 = third row). An IF statement can be based on this now :)

Comment: To know what Object corresponds to an element (good candidate for a question, of interest for anyone), you may either use a visual tool like [SAP ScreenReader tool in note 1441550 - SAP GUI scripting: Sample applications](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1441550/E) or [Scripting Tracker by Stefan Schnell](https://tracker.stschnell.de/index.htm). Or you may know the equivalences of ID prefix (`tbl` in `tblSAPMM61RTC_EZ`), and I can provide the list if you ask a separate question (because I don't know any public or SAP link about it).

Comment: I think your comments 2 and 3 are about pure VBA: if you want to loop, remove "Exit Do" which exits the loop. To look at variable row `j` instead of constant 2, use `tableControl.GetCell(CStr(j),5)`. Don't use `CStr` which Converts its argument to a String, GetCell expects a number, not a string.

Comment: The property `RowCount` is the number of actual lines in the table control, based on what I see in your screenshot, if there's no page above, it should return `2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237631/discussion-between-adde-and-sandra-rossi).